# Why is Vue failing to register my component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have written the following Vue component in the file `app/resources/js/components/class/createComponent.vue`:

```
        <template>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row justify-content-center">
            <div class = "col-md-8">
                <div class = "card card-default">
                    <div class = "card-header">Create Class</div>
                    <form action = "api/class/store" method = "POST" @submit = "createClass()">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <input type = "text" name = "name" v-model = "name" placeholder = "Class Name" class = "form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" class = "btn btn-info">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
    <script>
        export default {
        name: "createComponent",
        data() {
            return {
                name : ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createClass() {
                axios.post('api/class/store', {
                    name: this.name
                })
            }
        }
        }
    </script>
    <style scoped>
    
    </style>
```

I register the component thusly in `app/resources/js/app.js`:

```
Vue.component('class-create', require('./components/class/createComponent.vue').default);
```

However, HTML fails to load the element in `home.blade.php` with the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <class-create> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Oddly, `home.blade.php` loads the `<example-component>` fine, but cannot load my custom component. Can someone identify what I did wrong? Thanks.

**Edit**. Is it possible that this has to do with compiling the `app.js` file in `public/js` rather than `resources/js`?

Comment: How are you running? `php artisan serve`?  You might try restarting that. Sometimes with vue, the hot reload doesn't seem to work well for changes to the root file (app.js in your case)

Comment: `php artisan serve`, yes. I've restarted the server repeatedly, but it doesn't seem to help.